# imagemagick gradient mask file creation

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick

I'm playing with this creative script here: http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/transitions/. The plan is to mimic what happens with the script with `ffmpeg` and generate video with transition effects between pictures. My current understanding is this:

1. I have two pictures A and B.
2. I need in between a couple of pictures (say 15) that are partially A and partially B.
3. To do that I use the `composite -compose src-over A.jpg B.jpg mask-n.jpg out.jpg` command.
4. During the process, the mask-n.jpg gets generated automatically that gradually change from all black to all white.
5. Depends on the mathematically equations, the way the transition effect looks is different.

In one of the example, Fred the author gave this:

```
convert -size 128x128 gradient: maskfile.jpg
```

This will generate a image like this:
[image]

This is partially black and partially white. For the transition to work, I'll need an all white one and an all black one and a couple of others in between. What's the magical command to do that?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sorry about the late response. I've edited the question. Hopefully it makes more sense what I'm trying to do. Please help

Comment: Sorry, I still can't get what you mean. Can you draw it in Photoshop maybe? I showed you an all black one and an all white one - did they work? If not, what is wrong with them?

Answer (score 1):

I have re-read your question and I am still not sure I understand, but maybe you want a dark grey to light grey gradient:

```
convert -size 128x128 gradient:"rgb(40,40,40)-rgb(200,200,200)" greygrad.png
```

Not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, but if you want *an all black one*, use:

```
convert -size 128x128 xc:black black.jpg
```

and an all white one:

```
convert -size 128x128 xc:white white.jpg
```

and a grey one:

```
convert -size 128x128 xc:gray40 gray40.jpg
```

If you want to join them for transitions, use

```
convert im1.jpg im2.jpg -append result.jpg
```

or use `+append` to join side by side instead of above and below.

Consider using PNG instead of JPEG throughout.

Answer (score 1):

Fred tells you how the script works at the bottom of the page you have linked to with some example code.

According to his explanation there is only the one mask images as:

> The mask images is gradually made lighter

Comment: how to make the mask image lighter gradually?

Comment: I am not an expert but it looks like this is the method of changing the mask lightness: \( $maskfile -evaluate add $aa% \) "Alter channel pixels by evaluating an arithmetic, relational, or logical expression." I would guess each time through the loop it modifies the pixels to make them lighter.

Comment: Another way to do it would be to have a mask that was three times the height of your image. Top third white; gradiant in the middle and bottom third black. You could then start with the white section and move your mask up a little bit each time through the loop.